# How to unstack two columns from groupby()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have the below code to count how many product does each sale person sold in different locations

```
df = df.groupby(['location','sales person','item']).size().unstack().fillna(0) 
df.to_excel(r'c:\users\Tom\Project\info.xlsx')
```

The output I have is as below, but I need to fill the empty cell in column A, that means I want to see 'East' on row 3 and 'West' on row 5. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: try `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before you write the excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df.reset_index().to_excel(r'c:\users\Tom\Project\info.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `reset_index` method:

```
df.reset_index().to_excel(r'c:\users\Tom\Project\info.xlsx')
```

I don't have your data obviously, but here's a similar example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
d = df.groupby(['species','petal_length'])['sepal_length'].describe()
d
d.reset_index()
```